# CGAffineTransformMakeRotation Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a tableView that I am rotating 90 degrees to the left with the setTransform method and CGAffineTransformMakeRotation:

```
    [horizontalModeTable setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI_2)];
```

This worked perfectly in a previous program that I was making, yet for some reason whenever I try to run this I get an Apple Mach-O Linker Error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
"_CGAffineTransformMakeRotation", referenced from:
  -[ScalePickerVC viewDidLoad] in ScalePickerVC.o
  -[ScalePickerVC tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] in ScalePickerVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does anybody understand why this is happening? I cannot tell any differences from another program which I used this, yet this one continues to give me an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` is declared in Core Graphics, and the linker is telling you that it's not seeing a definition of that symbol. You need to add the Core Graphics framework to your project.